# Umbraco / uBlogsy ASP.Net error when posting comments

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have an umbraco installation which uses the uBlogsy addon for the blog, which had problem and all i have managed to sort out apart from this last one which i get when posting a comment. Does anyone know what this means or has come across this before at all?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<umbraco.interfaces.INode> umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode.get_ChildrenAsList()'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<umbraco.interfaces.INode> umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode.get_ChildrenAsList()'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<umbraco.interfaces.INode> umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode.get_ChildrenAsList()'.]
   uBlogsy.Web.usercontrols.uBlogsy.Contact.CreateComment() in D:\_PROJECTS\uBlogsy\Branches\1.32_bugs_search\uBlogsy\uBlogsy\usercontrols\uBlogsy\Contact.ascx.cs:116
   uBlogsy.Web.usercontrols.uBlogsy.Contact.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\_PROJECTS\uBlogsy\Branches\1.32_bugs_search\uBlogsy\uBlogsy\usercontrols\uBlogsy\Contact.ascx.cs:60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: Are you using compatible versions of umbraco / uBlogsy?

Comment: Umbraco 4.7.2 is being used, and i think 2.1.1.1  for uBlogsy - i have it installed on local dev, qa and uat but all with same issue

Comment: looking at it now, that path seems totally wrong d:\_Projects one..... however i don't know where this configuration comes from.

Comment: Ah, is there anything in the config?

Comment: well that is the point, i dont know where the config is i am unable to find one for uBlogsy

Comment: There is a config file under the /config folder but I just took a look in one of my installations and there's nothing that can help there..